# Conditionally add a field to the output of the query

Tags: mysql, sql

want to select user_answer.status only if user_answer.user_id = 10

I use this SQL query, to return results from multiple tables (**question**, **q_t**, **tag**, **user_answer**)

SQL:

```
select question.text,group_concat(tag.text), count(user_answer.question_id) as tt
from question
left join q_t on question.id = q_t.wall_id
left join user_answer on question.id = user_answer.question_id
left join tag on q_t.tag_id = tag.id
where question.id in (1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005) 
group by  question.text
order by field(question.id,1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005)
```

result:

```
text                         text                  tt
where is England?         Geography,Continent      33
how many ...?             sport,Europe              2
```

I need to add new select **user_answer.status** from **user_answer** table, with condition (only applied to retrieve this selection):

```
select user_answer.status    
where user_answer.user_id = 10
```

how to add this condition?

thanks,

Comment: This makes your question confusing: "with condition (only applied to retrieve this selection)".  what did you try already ?

Comment: @Bulat I want to select status from user_answer table only if user_id = 10

Comment: do you want status field to be NULL if user_id != 10 ?

Comment: yea, but join condition should be validated

Comment: it is still difficult to guess how exactly results should look like, example will be helpful. consider SqlFiddle as well.

Comment: will update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CASE WHEN:

```
select 
  question.text,group_concat(tag.text), 
  count(user_answer.question_id) as tt, 
  CASE WHEN user_answer.user_id = 10 THEN user_answer.status ELSE NULL END as status
from question
left join q_t on question.id = q_t.wall_id
left join user_answer on question.id = user_answer.question_id
left join tag on q_t.tag_id = tag.id
where question.id in (1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005) 
group by  
  question.text,  
  CASE WHEN user_answer.user_id = 10 THEN user_answer.status ELSE NULL END
order by field(question.id,1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005);
```

If you want status to be applied to all questions you can use MAX:

```
select 
  question.text,group_concat(tag.text), 
  count(user_answer.question_id) as tt, 
  MAX(CASE 
        WHEN user_answer.user_id = 10 
        THEN user_answer.status 
        ELSE NULL 
       END) as status
from question
left join q_t on question.id = q_t.wall_id
left join user_answer on question.id = user_answer.question_id
left join tag on q_t.tag_id = tag.id
where question.id in (1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005) 
group by  
  question.text
order by field(question.id,1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005);
```

Comment: this is work fine, but it duplicate row to "count(user_answer.question id)" for total and for user with id = 10

Comment: updated the answer, again just guessing what the output might be.

Answer (score 0):

```
select question.text,group_concat(tag.text), count(user_answer.question_id) as tt
    ,if((user_answer.id=10),(select user_answer.status),(''))as status
    from question`enter code here`
    left join q_t on question.id = q_t.wall_id
    left join user_answer on question.id = user_answer.question_id
    left join tag on q_t.tag_id = tag.id
    where question.id in (1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005) 
    group by  question.text
    order by field(question.id,1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005)
```